# How to simplify inequality with absolute value?

Tags: inequality

How can I simplify the following inequality in terms of x?

$(|x| + 1)^2 \le 4$

I got up to here, but I did not know how to continue given the $\pm$ before the 2.

$|x| + 1 \le \pm2$

Answer (score 2):

In general, $y^2\leq 4$ implies $y\leq 2$ and $y\geq -2$, a.k.a. $-2\leq y\leq 2$. Note that we can't just square-root both sides for inequalities.

So your inequality becomes $|x|+1\leq 2$ and $|x|+1\geq -2$.

Note that $|x|+1\geq -2$ is always true since a nonnegative number plus one is clearly nonnegative and thus more than -2.

So we are left to solve $|x|+1\leq 2$:

$|x|\leq 1$

$-1\leq x\leq 1$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can disregard the $-$ in your $\pm2$, because $|x| + 1$ is always positive.

Then you have $|x| + 1 \le 2$, and subtracting 1 from both sides, $|x| \le 1$. Hence $-1 \le x \le 1$.